# How to reset counter number on page refresh in Firefox with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, firefox, numbers, counter

I'm noticed it is a bug or not... then other browsers like Chrome and Opera can reset counter number, but Firefox doesn't reset it...

Go to http://bksn.mx/opequimar/renta_descripcion.html

There a web page and go to thumbnails section, click right arrows until is maximum number, then refresh page (F5) and you see **"3 de 3"**, try it again and you will see **"5 de 3"** with Firefox.

The first number is counter and the last number is `size();` each to div of thumbnails.

There a script of number counter:

```
$("a.prevarrow1").click("click", function() {
  var qInput = $(this).parents(".quantityInput");
  var qText = qInput.find(".quantityText");
  var qValue = parseInt((qText.val())? qText.val() : 0);
  qText.val(Math.max(qValue - 1, (qInput.attr("min"))? qInput.attr("min") : -0xffff));
});

$("a.nextarrow1").click("click", function() {
  var qInput = $(this).parents(".quantityInput");
  var qText = qInput.find(".quantityText");
  var qValue = parseInt((qText.val())? qText.val() : 0);
  qText.val(Math.min(qValue + 1, (qInput.attr("max"))? qInput.attr("max") : 0xffff));
});
```

HTML of output:

```
<div class="quantityInput" min="0" max="64">
<p>Pags. &nbsp;
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="quantityText" value="1" />
   de &nbsp;<span></span></p>
<div class="absolute">
   <a class="prev prevarrow1"></a>

<a class="next nextarrow1"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

If is not possible, i accept the new scripts from yours.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the page number is stored in a textbox. Firefox, IE, and "Browsers going back to Netscape 1 (and almost certainly NCSA Mosaic)" [according to Brendan Eich](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46845) restore saved form data on reload, but not on shift-reload. Webkit-based browsers are indeed incompatible here.

The solution is to avoid using a textbox to display the number (change it to a <span>, change the span's value with jQuery's [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)) or to read the input's value on load and update the page's state appropriately (scrolling the thumbnails to the specified page number).